# How to catch promise error in custom function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a promise:

```
  return this.credentialFetch(url.href, {
            method: 'get',
            signal: abort.signal,
            headers: jsonHeaders,
        })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.ok) return res.json();
            })
            .catch(catchRequestError(res, this.globalService));
```

And function that is called when error occurs:

```
export function catchRequestError<T>(result: T, globalService: GlobalService) {
    globalService.emitHttpResponse(result);
}
```

I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(reason: any) => PromiseLike<never>'.
```

On the line:

```
.catch(catchRequestError(res, this.globalService));
```

How to handle promise error?

Comment: `.catch(catchRequestError(res, this.globalService));` **calls** `catchRequestError` and then passes its return value into `catch`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value to `foo`. To have `catchRequestError` get called if the promise rejects, pass a *function* into `catch` that will call it, e.g. `.catch(() => catchRequestError(res, this.globalService));`

Comment: Okay, but in place where I expect data I expect specific type not error:

   `let layersPolygons = await this.update();`

in `layersPolygons`

Comment: in error case it return void, but I expect data

Comment: Then you're handling errors at the wrong level. In general, you want to return the promise chain *without* using `catch` so that errors follow the chain. You only use `catch` at the topmost level. This is a **lot** easier when you use `async` functions and `await` rather than using `.then` and `.catch`, because the propagation happens automatically. For instance, your code above would be much simpler in an `async` function: https://pastebin.com/SmXAeFFH (I've assumed you want the function to reject when `res.ok` is false).